# RESTful API: get/set one "global" single resource without id

Tags: api, rest

## TL;DR

In my current API, I've got two endpoints to handle the context:

```
GET /context/get
POST /context/set '{"id": "123"}'
```

What's the recommended way of having this *global*, *id*-less state accessible from RESTful API?

**Please assume that the *context* concept can't be changed**.

## Background

Let's say I've got a user that is logged. He's by default assigned to a *context* that he can change.

After the context change, all the subsequent API calls will return different data, according to the context.

Example:

```
// Backend
Context = "Poland"
```

then

```
$ curl -X GET http://api.myapp.com/cities
```

will respond:

```
{
  "cities": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": Warszawa"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": Wrocław"
  }]
}
```

However, if you change the context:

```
// Backend
Context = "USA"
```

then, **the same** URL:

```
$ curl -X GET http://api.myapp.com/cities
```

should return the different set of data:

```
{
  "cities": [{
    "id": "3",
    "name": New York City"
  }, {
    "id": "4",
    "name": Boston"
  }]
}
```

## Question

As the *context* is just a *global state* on the backend side, it doesn't have an *id*. It doesn't belong to any collection either. Still, I want it to be accessible in the API. There are three possible solutions I see:

### Solution #1 - existing

Set a context

```
$ curl -X POST http://api.myapp.com/context/set '{"id": "123"}'
```

Get a context

```
$ curl -X GET http://api.myapp.com/context/get
```

This one doesn't really feel like a RESTful API and still, on the frontend side, I have to mock the id (using *ember-data*). And the resource name is *singular* instead of *plural*.

### Solution #2 - mocking the *id*

Set a context

```
$ curl -X POST http://api.myapp.com/context/1 '{"contextId": "123"}'
```

Get a context

```
$ curl -X GET http://api.myapp.com/context/1
```

Here I mock the *id* to always equal to one but I feel that it's super hacky and certainly not self-explanatory... Moreover, I've got a name conflict: `id` vs `contextId`. And the resource name is *singular* instead of *plural*.

### Solution #3 - actions

Set a context

```
$ curl -X POST http://api.myapp.com/context/actions/set '{"id": "123"}'
```

Get a context

```
$ curl -X GET http://api.myapp.com/context/actions/get
```

This is very similar to the first one but using `actions` that could be a part of my whole API design (taken from e.g. [gocardless](https://github.com/gocardless/http-api-design/blob/master/README.md). Still, I'll have a problem how to model it on the frontend side nicely. And the resource name is *singular* instead of *plural* again.

Is there any #4 option? How should I address this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your three solutions are RPC, not REST. Not only they are not stateless, but setting a resource to some other resource by setting an id is very RCP'ish.

A RESTful solution, if you really want to go that way, is to set the context in a header. The client should send a header like `X-ContextId` or something like that, and you determine the request context you need from that.

However, don't worry too much about being RESTful if that's not what your application requires. I recommend reading the answer here: [SOAP vs REST (differences)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884295/soap-vs-rest-differences/19884975#19884975)

Comment: Hey, that was a really helpful answer. The link you provided hits the point. I was surprised with http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven also. That's great reading. Your idea of headers is worth considering, thanks! (the X-Headers were deprecated:  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6648, still I could use my own one though). Learnt a lot! Thanks!

Comment: Hey, what about the situation, when the `context_id` is being passed through cookie but it's encoded (can't have sth like context_id=123 explicitly in the cookie)? Then, I still have to ask the server for the resource: `GET /context/get`

Comment: If you're asking if that is RESTful or not, the short answer is that cookies are never RESTful.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the recommended way of having this *global*, *id-less* state
>   accessible from RESTful API?

A RESTful API is [by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Stateless) **stateless**, no client context should be stored on the server between requests.

If you want your API to be RESTful, you'll have to pass this id with each request.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. As I noted at first, I can't change the concept of *context* state though. I hate the idea of my API not being RESTful either. So now, in not-super-ideal-real world - what's the best approach? How can I have 99% percent of my API being RESTful, and these 1% excections to be handled in a nicest possible way?

Comment: Look @PedroWerneck answer(s), his suggestion about the custom header should allow it.