# what is hypermedia , hypermedia controls, hypermedia formats

Tags: rest, controls, hateoas, hypermedia

I'm currently reading "Rest in practice" book . I'm unable to understand the following terminology Hypermedia , hypermedia format, hypermedia controls, Domain application protocol. The author was suggesting need for domain specific hypermedia format. I could hardly understand those. I googled these terms but couldnt find a right answer. Can anyone explain these terminologies and why we need domain specific hypermedia formats instead of application/xml ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hypermedia = the fact that client and server are talking in terms of some a uniform representation eg: hyper links.

---

HyperMedia Control = A resource needs to be have operation done on it. So for example a product is represented by the hyperlink domain/product/001
then resource can be operated (edited and deleted) on by hypermedia control domain/product/001/edit and domain/product/001/delete.

---

The biggest difference is in the approach. procedural systems first write the operations as state transitions in sequential code (java, etc), then the interactions are manufactured as hyperlinks to deliver HATEOAS.

But systems approached as interactions directly model interactions and hence delivers hyperlinks directly. A sample example is http://www.masterkube.com/hateoas_technology.html is here.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 100):

There's a lot of confusion about this, because most applications that call themselves REST don't use hypermedia and aren't REST at all.

**Hypermedia** is a generalization of hypertext for content other than HTML. You can say hypertext is a subset of hypermedia. Hypermedia can be HTML in a browser, with all links, buttons and everything that's rendered so you can browse a website, or it can be a XML or JSON document intended to be parsed by an automated client who will also follow links and actions like a human would do with a browser, clicking rendered links and buttons.

**HATEOAS** means the interaction of a client with a REST application must be driven by hypermedia, or to put it simply, the client should obtain all URIs for every resource it needs by following links in the representation of resources themselves, not by relying on out-of-band information, like URI patterns given in documentation, as many APIs do.

This is simpler than it sounds. It just means that the interaction between a client and a REST application should be exactly like a human browsing a website. Take Stack Overflow itself for example. There are Users, Questions and Answers. When you want to see a list of your questions, you don't go to a documentation website, get an URI template for listing your questions, fill a placeholder with your user id and paste it on your brownser. You simply click on a link to another document described as the list of questions, and you don't even care about what the exact URI is. That's what HATEOAS means in practice.

An **hypermedia forma**t defines the contract between client and server. It's the hyperlink-enabled data format you are using for a particular representation of a resource in an hypermedia application. For instance, if you have a User resource, you have to document what exactly clients should expect from a representation of that resource and how to parse the representation to extract the information. Before interacting with your API, your clients need to implement a parser to extract the information, they need to know what properties the resource has and what they mean, what link relations they should expect and what state transitions are available, etc.

**Hypermedia controls** are the combinations of protocol methods and link relations in an hypermedia format that tells the client what state transitions are available and how to perform them. For instance, a Question might have a `rel=post_answer` link that expects an Answer representation as the payload of a POST method and will create a new Answer resource related to it.

Once you have a set of hypermedia formats defined, you need a **domain specific media-type** to determine exactly what hypermedia format is being used for a particular interaction. A generic media-type like `application/xml` only tells the client how to parse the data format, it doesn't say anything about the information extracted by the parser. For instance, let's say a document has the media-type `application/vnd.mycompany.user.v1+xml`, the client knows it's a version 1.0 representation of the User resource in XML format. If you change the resource by adding or removing properties, links, etc, you can change the version number and clients won't break, since they can request the version they were implemented for by using the `Accept` header. You can also provide multiple formats for the same resource, like XML or JSON, and even a pretty human-readable representation in HTML.

When you wrap everything together -- the underlying protocol, HTTP; the contracts defined by hypermedia formats and media types -- you have your **Domain Application Protocol**, which is the whole set of resources and available state transitions advertised by your application.

Needless to say, 99% of the so-called REST APIs you'll find around the internet don't follow all of this. Most of them are simply HTTP APIs that follow some of the REST constraints, sometimes because they don't really need all of them, sometimes because that's what the developers thought REST really is.

Comment: So how does application/vnd.mycompany.user.v1+xml convey to the user about the information that has to be parsed ?

Comment: It doesn't. The documentation describing `application/vnd.mycompany.user.v1+xml` does.

Comment: Is it HATEOAS if an application does only provide the link to a ressource created by a POST in the location header of the response? Or does the term hypermedia only include links that are contained inside the body?

Comment: @Marv It depends on how clients other than the one who created the resource are going to retrieve it after creation. If nobody ever will, then fine. If they will use the Location URI saved somewhere else, fine. If they will construct the URI on their own, it's not HATEOAS.

Comment: "99% of the so-called REST APIs you'll find around the internet don't follow all of this" Where did you get this percentage from? Can you provide me with the source so I can cite it in my publication?

Comment: @disooqi That's an hyperbole, not a factual claim. You can probably find quite a few real hypermedia APIs now, but back in 2015 they were very rare.