# Difference in execution of SOAP based WCF from a Restful WCF

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-rest, wcf-rest-starter-kit, wcf-rest-starting-guide

Can anyone please tell what is the actual difference between a Restful WCF and a normal WCF service? 
By difference I basically means the difference in the way .net handles both the requests.
Is it like when we change a WCF service to Restful, using the WebGet and WebInvoke method, .net does all the processing as present in normal wcf like creating service host, creating service instance etc,along with that supports the HTTP Requests?

**I actually would like to know about WCF Services, how WCF execution cycle is different when it is a Restful WCF service from a normal SOAP based WCF.**

Comment: http://blog.smartbear.com/apis/understanding-soap-and-rest-basics/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884295/soap-vs-rest-differences