# Resources for understanding SOAP, HTTP,REST?

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, http, soap

I am a .net developer but I have no or very limited understanding of SOAP, HTTP,REST. What are some of the resources for learning more about them. Specially for a .NET developer. A general search on google returns a zillion of results but the ones I looked into did not help me understand how knowledge of these would be make me a better developer. I know basics of WCF, I thought it would be a good idea to learn more about SOAP, HTTP, REST etc before diving deeper in WCF etc.

Comment: I found answers on this very site the most revealing so far. As an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19884975/580651

Answer (score 0):

The most important stuff for you if you want learn web services should be HTTP protocol, soap and rest are the implementation details.

For the HTTP i would recommend this great serie of articles which i personally read. They explain the basic mechanisms and than the advanced ones of HTTP protocol.
[A Software Developer's Guide to HTTP](http://odetocode.com/Articles/741.aspx)

After understanding HTTP you can read about rest - basically simple web services using HTTP.
[What is rest](http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/what-is-rest.html)

At the end i would recommend for example this for soa/soap understanding, which you may end up using in WCF.
[Soap](http://www.service-architecture.com/articles/web-services/web_services_explained.html)

Also some comparation between soa/soap and rest can come handy.
[Soap vs Rest](http://blog.smartbear.com/apis/understanding-soap-and-rest-basics/)

Answer (score 0):

This [MSDN WCF article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx) seems to cover the basics of all three pretty well.

The (to me) most obvious resource: **Trial and Error** (mixed with [searching and reading a lot here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SOAP%20%7C%7C%20REST%20%7C%7C%20HTTP%20)). Dive right into WCF and figure out what is what on the way. (Found in a quick search: https://stackoverflow.com/a/186695/580651)

I had the best results by implementing HTTP, REST API and SOAP API clients and/or services running/setting up on servers by myself or integrating and analyzing the internals of a web service framework for a specific project where I had the need for one.

Some related topics that come to my mind (a quick shot):

- **[HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)** leads to [Status Codes](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), [CORS & OPTIONS preflight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), [going HTTPS only](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/), [HTTP 418](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2324) and eventually to [HTTP/2](https://http2.github.io/)
- **[REST](http://rest.elkstein.org/)** often leads to [JSON](http://www.json.org/), [CRUD operations and HTTP verbs](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), [maturity level](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) and [Hypermedia/HATEOAS](http://restcookbook.com/Basics/hateoas/)
- **[SOAP](https://www.w3.org/TR/soap/)** probably to [WSDL XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl)
- **[Securing Endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551/best-practices-for-securing-a-rest-api-web-service?rq=1)** is important in all cases.
- **Tools** that help forging and analyzing requests and their responses. (e.g. [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) or REST/SOAP client browser extensions)
- Consuming open data and building services that make the world a better place is a plus.