# To which layer of the web service protocol stack does rest belong to?

Tags: rest

I know that SOAP belongs to the message protocol layer. So, does "REST" also belong in the same layer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is RESTful programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming)

Answer (score 1):

The debate between REST and SOAP has been going on for a long time, and so there is a lot of information about it.

REST is a communication protocol. An acceptable definition can be the following:

> REST stands for Representational State Transfer. (It is sometimes
>   spelled "ReST".) It relies on a stateless, client-server, cacheable
>   communications protocol

From [elkstein.org](http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/what-is-rest.html)

A more formal definition can be found in the [REST Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

REST does not belong anywhere. It is a protocol (a way of doing things), mostly used with HTTP, but it can be used with anything.

The next thing that usually comes, is SOAP vs REST. And for that, I do suggest you do some reading and decide on your own which one you should use. I recommend the following articles in the given order:

1. [Understanding SOAP and REST Basics And Differences](http://blog.smartbear.com/apis/understanding-soap-and-rest-basics/)
2. [REST Vs SOAP, The Difference Between Soap And Rest](http://spf13.com/post/soap-vs-rest)
3. [SOAP vs REST (differences)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884295/soap-vs-rest-differences)