# What is the difference between SOAP and REST API in Maximo (Maximo Asset Management)?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maximo, maximo-anywhere

Starting from Maximo 7.6 or above. I see Maximo supports both REST API and SOAP. I do not understand the difference between them.
I find that Maximo (**Maximo Integration Framework**) supports web service (SOAP) but Maximo still uses REST API.
Can you help me?

Comment: Please, help me? Thanks

Comment: Is your question a general SOAP vs. REST or do you only care about the two API's for Maximo?  For the second one you'll likely do better in a [Maximo forum](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communitystart?communityUuid=86e48e5e-4ee6-4fa2-a408-6311e401e19f) than here.  For the first, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884295/soap-vs-rest-differences).

Comment: Thanks but I only care about  the two API's for Maximo. Can you help me?

Comment: If I can say so kindly, this question is way too open ended and shows no effort to find answers. A basic search for "REST vs SOAP" on Google turned up a great post on SO that answered the question.

Comment: @stunbar The IBM forum link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both indeed. There are huge possibilities for REST clients using Maximo REST web server, the REST clients can get/update/delete data in Maximo (https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/restguide/Maximo_Nextgen_REST_API.html). It is already implemented and you can setup REST support in Maximo (make it available for use) by changing few xml configuration files. REST services are "build in", you can't modify them.

External REST APIs can be called by using a configured HTTP end point in Maximo Integration.

You can create your own SOAP web-service by Click->Next->Click :) from Object Structure in Maximo Integration and provide generated by Maximo WSDL for SOAP client.

Comment: So, What's the difference between them?. Why Maximo support both?. When to use rest?. When to use SOAP service?. Thanks

Comment: it depends pretty much on the requirements and the possibilities of the system you are going to integrate with.

Comment: Maximo supports both because Maximo is good software; it goes the extra mile to make it easier to integrate with whatever system the customer needs to integrate it with. If those systems need SOAP, Maximo can do that. If they need REST, put a check in that box. Given the choice, I would go with REST, because it's easier.

Comment: For the difference between REST and SOAP and when to use which, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884295/soap-vs-rest-differences).